# Android: Read app's settings from the another app

Tags: android, settings

I have two android games, this games store their data (scores, other settings) in the app's settings. I would love to develop an android widget where data from these two games should be shown. So is possible to read app's settings from the other app (in my case from the widget)? How can I do it?

Thanks,
Yakov

Comment: Did you develop the two android games yourself?

Comment: Actually it should looks like the High Scores Widget of my games :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you developed those two games, it makes using their data so much easier. You have a couple of options now. But for all of those options, I'd recommend enforcing a permission: [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) so that applications that you don't want accessing your data can't access it. Here are your options:

1. [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) but using [`getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
2. [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)
3. [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)
4. [Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) with a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)